# How to add loading bar to the adapter class where the view is inside another activity

Tags: android, kotlin, activity-indicator

I'm trying to add `loadingbar` inside the adapter class where the view of the same is inside the mainactivity.I've used `doAsync` method to load an app when clicking on the app icon which is inside the mainactivity.
Following is the error that I'm getting while using loadingbar inside  the `doAsync` method.

> android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Below is the Adapter class

`Adapter.kt`

```
class Adapter(ctx: Context, private val appInfoList: ArrayList<AppInfoModel>, private val contentResolver: ContentResolver,
              private val packageManager: PackageManager,
              private val loadingIndicator: AVLoadingIndicatorView,
              private val applicationContext: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.MyViewHolder>()  {
    private val inflater: LayoutInflater

    init {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): Adapter.MyViewHolder {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Adapter.MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        var itemView: View? = null
        holder.appIcon.setImageDrawable(appInfoList[position].appIcon)
        holder.appName.setText(appInfoList[position].appName)
        holder.versionNumber.setText(appInfoList[position].versionNumber)
        if (!appInfoList[position].isInstalled) {
            holder.appInfoCard.foreground = ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#CCFFFFFF"))
            holder.appInfoCard.isEnabled = false
            holder.warningIcon.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
        holder.appInfoCard.setOnClickListener() {
            Log.e("App opened", appInfoList[position].appName)
            var loadingBar:AVLoadingIndicatorView= loadingIndicator.findViewById(R.id.avi)
            Log.d("Loading bar", loadingBar.toString())
            doAsync {
                try {
                    loadingBar!!.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    LauncherUtils.setDynamicConfig(contentResolver, packageManager,applicationContext, appInfoList[position].auxName!!, appInfoList[position].packageName!!)
                }
                catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.e("Exception-launcher", e.toString())
                }
                uiThread {

                    //loadingBar!!.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can not touch Views from background thread in android . So move `loadingBar` part ouside of block . Are you are using `Anko` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the stacktrace says, you shouldn't set visibility of any view from a background thread. Probably moving `loadingBar!!.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` to `uiThread{}` will solve your issue.